# Mocking an interface defined in a test file: interface "Undefined"?

Tags: go, go-testing

This is a bug which I've attempted to reproduce with a minimal example, but so far unsuccessfully. The Go module is similar to the following:

```
.
├── go.mod
└── handler
    ├── handler.go
    ├── handler_test.go
    └── mock_handler.go
```

where `handler.go` is empty (contains `package handler` only), `handler_test.go` contains a `Handler` interface definition (which is the same as Go's `http.Handler`) and a placeholder test,

```
package handler

import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"
)

type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
}

func TestMockHandler(t *testing.T) {
    mockHandler := MockHandler{}
    t.Log(mockHandler)
}
```

and `mock_handler.go` contains a `MockHandler` struct which implements the `Handler` interface and is generated using [`moq`](https://github.com/matryer/moq):

```
// Code generated by moq; DO NOT EDIT.
// github.com/matryer/moq

package handler

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var (
    lockMockHandlerServeHTTP sync.RWMutex
)

// Ensure, that MockHandler does implement Handler.
// If this is not the case, regenerate this file with moq.
var _ Handler = &MockHandler{}

// MockHandler is a mock implementation of Handler.
//
//     func TestSomethingThatUsesHandler(t *testing.T) {
//
//         // make and configure a mocked Handler
//         mockedHandler := &MockHandler{
//             ServeHTTPFunc: func(in1 http.ResponseWriter, in2 *http.Request)  {
//                 panic("mock out the ServeHTTP method")
//             },
//         }
//
//         // use mockedHandler in code that requires Handler
//         // and then make assertions.
//
//     }
type MockHandler struct {
    // ServeHTTPFunc mocks the ServeHTTP method.
    ServeHTTPFunc func(in1 http.ResponseWriter, in2 *http.Request)

    // calls tracks calls to the methods.
    calls struct {
        // ServeHTTP holds details about calls to the ServeHTTP method.
        ServeHTTP []struct {
            // In1 is the in1 argument value.
            In1 http.ResponseWriter
            // In2 is the in2 argument value.
            In2 *http.Request
        }
    }
}

// ServeHTTP calls ServeHTTPFunc.
func (mock *MockHandler) ServeHTTP(in1 http.ResponseWriter, in2 *http.Request) {
    if mock.ServeHTTPFunc == nil {
        panic("MockHandler.ServeHTTPFunc: method is nil but Handler.ServeHTTP was just called")
    }
    callInfo := struct {
        In1 http.ResponseWriter
        In2 *http.Request
    }{
        In1: in1,
        In2: in2,
    }
    lockMockHandlerServeHTTP.Lock()
    mock.calls.ServeHTTP = append(mock.calls.ServeHTTP, callInfo)
    lockMockHandlerServeHTTP.Unlock()
    mock.ServeHTTPFunc(in1, in2)
}

// ServeHTTPCalls gets all the calls that were made to ServeHTTP.
// Check the length with:
//     len(mockedHandler.ServeHTTPCalls())
func (mock *MockHandler) ServeHTTPCalls() []struct {
    In1 http.ResponseWriter
    In2 *http.Request
} {
    var calls []struct {
        In1 http.ResponseWriter
        In2 *http.Request
    }
    lockMockHandlerServeHTTP.RLock()
    calls = mock.calls.ServeHTTP
    lockMockHandlerServeHTTP.RUnlock()
    return calls
}
```

In order to generate `mock_handler.go`, I initially defined the `Handler` in `handler.go` and then, in the `handler` directory, ran the command

```
 moq -out mock_handler.go . Handler
```

I subsequently moved the `Handler` interface definition to `handler_test.go` since it is only intended to be used for tests.

In this simplified example, I'm able to run `go test` in package list mode in the root directory:

```
~/g/s/g/k/mockhandler> go test ./... -count=1
ok      github.com/kurtpeek/mockhandler/handler 0.448s
```

My 'actual' module has a similar structure, similar to the following:

```
.
├── cmd
│   └── root.go
├── images
├── main.go
└── vpp
    ├── ensure_license_test.go
    └── mock_handler.go
```

The `Handler` interface is defined in exactly the same way in `ensure_license_test.go` as in `handler_test.go` in the simplified module; `ensure_license_test.go` starts like this:

```
package vpp

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/url"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
}

type MockTestServer struct {
    TestServer  *httptest.Server
    MockHandler *MockHandler
}
```

`mock_handler.go` is also exactly the same as `mock_handler.go` in the simplified module (except for the package name).

Yet when I run `go test ./...` in the root directory of the 'actual' module, I get an `undefined` error for `Handler`:

```
~/g/s/g/f/vpp-client> go test ./... -count=1
# github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client/vpp
vpp/mock_handler.go:17:7: undefined: Handler
ok      github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client/vpp    0.128s
```

Strangely, when I run this from within the `vpp` package, it passes:

```
> go test ./... -count=1
ok      github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client/vpp    0.601s
```

What could be the reason that `go test` is unable to define the definition of `Handler` when running it in package list mode from the root directory as in the first example?

Comment: Do not have your normal source files reference identifiers that were declared in a test file. If you need to reference `Handler` in the source file then simply declare it in a source file. Why? Because when you import a package you're only importing the source files, not the test files and if one of those source files references an identifier declared in a test file that is not included by the import you get the *undefined* compiler error.

Comment: That means that when you do `go test ./...` it is not the `vpp` package that is failing, it is one of the other packages, one that imports `vpp`, that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was the `cmd` package for which tests were failing because it was unable to import the `Handler` interface from a test file in the `vpp` package. So I changed line 17 of `mock_handler.go` to use an `http.Handler` rather than a `Handler`:

```
var _ http.Handler = &MockHandler{}
```

Now the tests pass:

```
~/g/s/g/f/vpp-client> go test ./...
?       github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client    [no test files]
?       github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client/cmd    [no test files]
ok      github.com/fleetsmith/vpp-client/vpp    0.462s
```

I was also able to delete the definition of the `Handler` interface from `ensure_license_test.go` since I'm now using the definition from the `http` standard library directly.

The drawback of this approach is that it requires editing code that was auto-generated by `moq`, however, I wasn't able to figure out how to run `moq` to mock interfaces in Go's standard library and in any case this interface is unlikely to change.